# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while [WKInterfaceTable setNumberOfRows:withRowType]

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, watchos-2, nsthread, wkinterfacetable

I wanna to update table from a background thread using this part of the code

```
 __block typeof(self.tableB) self_tableB = self.tableB;
    [lwc setBaseControllerCallback:^(int ndx) {
        __block typeof(ndx) ndx_t = ndx;
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self_tableB setNumberOfRows: 0 withRowType:TABLEELEMENT];
            [self_tableB setNumberOfRows: ndx_t withRowType:TABLEELEMENT];
        }];

    }];
```

where

```
^(int ndx) {
//...
}
```

is a block called from background thread (NSThread) and lwc - is an instance of my custom background thread class.

To clear this method is called like with:
//code inside thread
    if (handlerBase_inner) {
    handlerBase_inner(ndx++);
    }

So, at
`[self_tableB setNumberOfRows: ndx_t withRowType:TABLEELEMENT];`
I can see `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Why? What is the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worry about self_tableB. I'm not sure that you want a strong reference to it, artificially keeping it alive might cause it to have a dangling pointer back to its delegate.

`__block __weak typeof(self.tableB) self_tableB = self.tableB;`

Adding a weak annotation might to the trick.